# Changing only non-admin players' gamemode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When a player joins the server, this command block (containing `gamemode 2 @a`) puts them into gamemode 2/adventure mode. How can I change this so that only non-admin/not "opped" players' gamemode gets changed?

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes I have tryed

Comment: Awesome!  So show us what you've tried, so we have an idea of what we're working with.

Comment: Give more details as well.  Is the server not adventure mode?  Is this designed to lock the new players in somewhere?  Why not use spawn protection to prevent blocks from being broken?  How many op players do you have?

Comment: Just set the default gamemode to adventure..?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an automatic way to differentiate admins. But since the number of admins should be low, you can just tag them all manually using:

```
/tag <name> add admin
```

Then you replace the command in your command block with:

```
/gamemode adventure @a[tag=!admin]
```

Also, an improvement: If you click the button in the command block GUI saying <kbd>Impulse</kbd> twice, it changes to <kbd>Repeat</kbd> and the command block turns blue. Then click on <kbd>Needs redstone</kbd> to change it to <kbd>Always active</kbd> and you can just remove the redstone clock next to it. The command block will continue to run, take immediate effect and produce less lag.

And lastly, you can improve performance further by restricting the number of affected players to only the ones that are in the default gamemode of the server. If that's for example Survival mode, you can use:

```
/gamemode adventure @a[tag=!admin,gamemode=survival]
```